# Как загрузить рисунок?

Tags: html5, javascript

Есть html5 рисовалка, код брал [отсюда](http://modusponens.info/2011/02/html5-paint-1/). Теперь есть необходимость загружать творения пользователя на сервер. На сайте написано, что можно открыть рисунок с помощью

```
window.open(document.getelementbyid("canvas").todataurl("image/png"), "new_window_name");
```

Как загрузить этот рисунок, не показывая пользователю (это должно происходить периодически)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сохранение служит только для клиента, то просто сохранять base64, т.е.:

```
$.ajax({
   url:'/filesave/',
   type:'POST',
   data: {'imageBase64':document.getelementbyid("canvas").todataurl("image/png")}
});
```

Comment: спасибо, прям то что надо

Comment: после этого кода массив $_FILES пуст
как мне обработать файл на сервере(сохранить его)

Comment: а он не файл, а пост.... ищите в нем...